# Thread safe java finite state machine (FSM)

Tags: java, multithreading, fsm

I have seen quite a few FSM implementations for JAVA, but I am not sure if there are any "reusable" ones. What do I mean by reusable?

I am processing state transitions for multiple objects with various states. I want to  configure a singleton state machine which obviously itself needs to be stateless and thread-safe, so I can just pass all given objects to have their state transitions executed possible in parallel.

I wonder if there are any suitable ones for this scenario out there?

Comment: How can you have a stateless, state machine?  Do you want a state machine per thread?  I that case you don't need a singleton.

Comment: I need a FSM which can process many objects in parallel. In order for state machine to process multiple objects' transitions in parallel it needs to keep each process's data out of its own state. That is what I mean by stateless, but I agree it is not the best choice of terms.

Comment: I would model that as a state machine per thread.  This way the state is thread local or task local.

Answer (score 3):

This may be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10875317/recommended-fsm-finite-state-machine-library-for-java but it is hard to be sure.  I have used SMC in a multithreaded system before.

Simpler state machine which may suit you is to use an enum like this.

http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2011/06/java-secret-using-enum-as-state-machine.html

Again, this is how I have written them from scratch.

Comment: No these are quite different, there they state "It wouldn't have to be concurrent capable or multi-threaded."

Comment: Damn after all those years with Java and presumably knowing the JLS quite well I just found out that you could create anonymous classes of enum singletons. I mean it doesn't necessarily strike me as clearer than the standard while loop method, but it's interesting nonetheless.

Comment: @husayt You can use them concurrently by having more than one state machine.  BTW The example I gave using `enum` is stateless.